# Hide image in Fancy Box modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox

I am using a CMS and its media uploader which generates thumbnails and does batch resize for modal popup images. Among all uploaded images the CMS uses the first one as the main image for an article and the others for the article gallery. But in the gallery modal there is always this first main image shown. I need to avoid/hide it in FancyBox modal.

I successfully hide the generated thumbnail on the sites frontend which is the first/main image in the thumbnail grid, but when I click on any other thumbnail (open the gallery) and reach the end of the gallery this hidden image is shown. Even if I set `'loop' : false` to FancyBox it keeps being shown.

So, I need option to disable preview of a particular image in FancyBox (version: 2.1.5) modal popup where all images are wrapped as `gallery -> rel="gallery"`.

Is there any way to disable it via JavaScript or any other way?

Comment: Do you have any sample code we can look at?

Comment: Hi @Danny H 
this is frontend code https://jsfiddle.net/wk6mj3qn/

For FancyBox I am using 2.1.5 version which is initialised properly